# How find this limit $\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac{(2n)!}{2^n\cdot n!}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\cdot \cdots$

Tags: limits

Find this limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{(2n)!}{2^n\cdot n!}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\left(\tan{\left(\dfrac{\pi\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}}{4\sqrt[n]{n!}}\right)}-1\right)$$

I know we must use this 
$$n!\approx\left(\dfrac{n}{e}\right)^{n}\sqrt{2n\pi}$$
so
$$\dfrac{\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}\approx\dfrac{n+1}{n}\dfrac{\sqrt[n+1]{2(n+1)\pi}}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}\to 1,n\to \infty$$
But I can't .Thank you

Comment: This is Problem 11771 from The American Mathematical Monthly Vol 121, No. 4, April (2014)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{(2n)!}{2^n\cdot n!}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\left(\tan{\left(\dfrac{\pi\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}}{4\sqrt[n]{n!}}\right)}-1\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{(2n)!}{2^n\cdot (n!)^2}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\cdot\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n!}\left(\tan{\left(\dfrac{\pi\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}}{4\sqrt[n]{n!}}\right)}-1\right)= \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\cdot\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n$$
1) Apply root criterion (Chauchy-d'Alembert): $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(2n+2)!}{2^{n+1}\cdot((n+1)!)^2}\cdot\frac{2^n\cdot(n!)^2}{(2n)!} =2$$
2) Note $\dfrac{\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}=c_n$$$\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n= \lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n!}\cdot(\tan(\frac{\pi}{4}c_n)-1)= \lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n!}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{2}\sin\frac{\pi}{4}(c_n-1)}{\cos\frac{\pi}{4}c_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n!}\cdot\frac{2\sin\frac{\pi}{4}(c_n-1)}{\frac{\pi}{4}(c_n-1)}\cdot\frac{\pi}{4}(c_n-1)=\frac{\pi}{2}\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n!}\cdot(c_n-1)= \frac{\pi}{2}\cdot\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}-\sqrt[n]{n!}) =\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{e} = \frac{\pi}{2e}.$$

Applied $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}-\sqrt[n]{n!}) = \frac{1}{e}$$ the Lalescu's Sequence.(See http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/blog/44744 )

Conclusion $$L=  \frac{\pi}{e}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Replace all factorials with their [Stirling approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), and apply [l'Hopital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27Hopital%27s_rule) as many times as necessary. The end result should be $\dfrac\pi e$

Comment: Hello,can you post you more detailed?and How use LHopital's rule?

Comment: The first half should easily simplify to $\dfrac ne$ . Then we re-write the whole thing as $\dfrac{\tan(\ldots)-1}{\dfrac en}$ , and apply l'Hopital's rule to the dreadful expression of the form $\dfrac00$, where factorials have been replaced with self-powers.